# Динамическая смена изображений

Tags: android

Предположим, есть программа, и в ней, в зависимости от условия определённого, должен меняться цвет изображения. Например с черного на белый. Я додумался только до того, что бы программно устанавливать заранее заготовленные картинки, но может быть есть другой, менее костыльный способ?

Comment: Всмысле, просто чёрный/белый квадрат?

Comment: Нет, не просто квадрат. Но изображение само по себе черно/белое

Comment: Я смотрел картинки из ресурсов приложения вк, так вот, там фильтры реализованы обычными картинками. Не знаю как это работает, скорее всего она как маска на фото накладывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если картинка у вас в `ImageView`, то можно менять цвет через метод `setColorFilter`.